# Extending a Type to Create Child Type

Tags: typescript, types, extends

I am working with TypeScript and am wondering how to achieve a `child` type of another. I don't know exactly how to describe what I am after, so let me just show an example.

```
type Person = {
 name: string;
 type: PersonType
}

type Child = Person & {
 type: PersonType.child,
}

enum PersonType {
 adult = "adult",
 child = "child",
}

const people: Person[] = [...];
const children: Child[] = people.filter(p => p.type === PersonType.child);
```

Is this something I would use a generic for? I would think this is straight forward and I'm just missing a piece. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added redundant `=` sign to enum.

```js
type Person = {
    name: string;
    type: PersonType
}

type Child = Person & {
    type: PersonType.child,
}

enum PersonType {
    adult = "adult",
    child = "child",
}

type TestChild = Person extends Child ? true : false // false
type TestPerson = Child extends Person ? true : false // true


const people: Person[] = [{ name: 'John', type: PersonType.adult }, { name: 'Tim', type: PersonType.child }];
const children: Child[] = people.filter(p => p.type === PersonType.child);
```

The problem is that Child extends Person, but not vice versa.
You can't just use explicitly type `Child[]` for `children` constant, because `Person` does not extends `Child`

[Here](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) is interesting article about covariance.

**But**, you can achieve desired behaviour, just use `filter` as a typeguard:

```js
const children: Child[] = people.filter((p):p is Child => p.type === PersonType.child); // ok
```

More interesting examples, You can find [here](https://catchts.com/tuples#filter)